# Question regarding notation of Total Variance

Tags: real-analysis

I am working through some explanations of Total Variance of a function and am a little bit confused as to why Total Variance is denoted with an open interval.

To elaborate, in my notes I have that if f is of bounded variation on a closed interval [a,b], then Total Variation is defined as $$V_f (a,b) =\sup\{\sum_{P}|f(x_{j+1})−f(x_j)| : P \mbox{ partition of } [a,b]\}.$$

Apologize for the lack of formatting knowledge.  My question is this:  Why is Total Variation $(V_f (a,b))$ written with an open interval around $a$ and $b$ while the partitions used to define the sum explicitly involve the closed interval from $a$ to $b$?  Since Partitions require $x_0 = a$ and $x_n= b$, why does the notation for Total Variance, $V_f (a,b)$ use an open interval around $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wonder why we write $V_f(a,b)$ as opposed to $V_f[a,b]$? It's just *notation*. $V_f(a,b)$ does *not* refer to the total variation on $(a,b)$ but on $[a,b]$, as you correctly pointed out.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Definitions) for example uses the notation $V_a^b(f)$. So, don't get confused by the notation.

Continuously differentiable functions have bounded variation but Brownian motion or $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ are examples of functions with unbounded variation.

Comment: Thank you Alex, that perfectly answers my question!  I was worried that I was missing something about the definition, but I think you've cleared away my confusion.